# HBASE 0.96 Release Date

Tags: hbase

Does anyone know an estimate of when HBase 0.96 (Singularity) will be released? I looking to start using it with Hadoop 2.0. I couldn't see anything on hbase.apache.org.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With HBase, or any other open source project for that matter, your best bet is consulting its issue tracker.

For your particular question, tracking [0.96 summary on HBase JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE/fixforversion/12320040) should give you a good 'estimate'. As of today, there are 6 unresolved tickets, with patches available for two of them, so first RC might be expected pretty soon.

Also, there is [this discussion](http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/DISCUSSION-Sorting-out-issues-for-0-96-for-eventual-release-td4036318.html) in the mailing list.